# Coding a triple-state Boolean in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, boolean

I know that a Boolean can have only 2 values, false and true. And I can code a Class that has a property that can have 3 states. But how can I code it in such a way so that, when setting or getting its state, I can refer to the object itself as opposed its property? eg:

```
var triBoolean:TriBoolean = 0;  
// later...  
triBoolean = 1;
```

The reason I want to do this is so I can have a value that toggles through three states and I'm assuming it would be quicker to refer directly to the object - but perhaps that's not right.
Or is it only primitive types that can be used in this way?

Comment: What do you mean "quicker"? Quicker for what?

Comment: I mean quicker to process. Quicker THAN referring to a property, not quicker FOR anything (other than speed). But I could be wrong...

Comment: I don't think you wan't a Boolean, wikipedia (In computer science, the Boolean or logical data type is a data type, having two values), It looks as if you really wan't an Enum, though this is not native to the AS3 language there are a few implementations floating around the web: http://www.herrodius.com/blog/87

Comment: If you want something fast, you can use bitwise operators on integer. Though I would only recommend if it's something you checking multiple times at 60 frames per second. If it's a business logic just go with Enums, they are easier to refactor in future.

Comment: I know I don't want a Boolean - I know it only has two values; I want a custom triple-state Boolean-LIKE Class. I may look into Enums, thanks - Unless anyone has any other ideas...

Answer (score 0):

If you use an `Object` type you can do it, having: (null, true or false)  tri-state, you will lose type safety, but still valid:

```
 var triBoolean:Object = null;
 // Then you can assign your triple states...
 triBoolean = false; //valid
 triBoolean = true;  //valid
 triBoolean = null;  //valid
```